# Ruby Regex Match Between "foo" and "bar"

Tags: ruby, regex

I have unfortunately wandered into a situation where I need regex using Ruby.  Basically I want to match this string after the underscore and before the first parentheses.  So the end result would be 'table salt'.

```
_____ table salt (1)   [F]
```

As usual I tried to fight this battle on my own and with rubular.com.  I got the first part

```
^_____ (Match the beginning of the string with underscores ).
```

Then I got bolder,

```
^_____(.*?) ( Do the first part of the match, then give me any amount of words and letters after it )
```

Regex had had enough and put an end to that nonsense and crapped out.  So I was wondering if anyone on stackoverflow knew or would have any hints on how to say my goal to the Ruby Regex parser.

EDIT: Thanks everyone, this is the pattern I ended up using after creating it with rubular.

```
ingredientNameRegex = /^_+([^(]*)/;
```

Everything got better once I took a deep breath, and thought about what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `^[_]+([^(]*)\(`

It will match lines starting with one or more underscores followed by anything not equal to an opening bracket: http://rubular.com/r/vthpGpVr4y

Comment: this is true, i just added the character class for clarity

Comment: Note that you will want to call `strip` on your `$1` result to remove leading and trailing whitespace. Also, IMHO adding unnecessary square brackets to the already-line-noise nature of regex adds complexity, not clarity.

Answer (score 7):

```
str = "_____ table salt (1)   [F]"
p str[ /_{3}\s(.+?)\s+\(/, 1 ]
#=> "table salt"
```

That says:

- Find at least three underscores
- and a whitespace character (`\s`)
- and then one or more (`+`) of any character (`.`), but as little as possible (`?`), up until you find
- one or more whitespace characters,
- and then a literal `(`

The parens in the middle save that bit, and the `1` pulls it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's working regex:

```
str = "_____ table salt (1)   [F]"
match = str.match(/_([^_]+?)\(/)
p match[1].strip # => "table salt"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^_____\s*([^(]+?)\s*\(
```

---

`^_____` match the underscore from the beginning of string

`\s*` matches any whitespace character

`(` grouping start
    `[^(]+` matches all non `(` character at least once
    `?`      matches the shortest possible string (non greedy)
`)` grouping end

`\s*` matches any whitespace character

`\(` find the `(`

Comment: You might want a `strip` on the result.

Comment: You don't escape ( when it's inside []

Answer (score 0):

```
 "_____ table salt (1) [F]".gsub(/[_]\s(.+)\s\(/, ' >>>\1<<< ')
 # => "____ >>>table salt<<< 1) [F]"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the simplest regex to do what you want is:

```
/^_____ ([\w\s]+) /
```

That says: 
leading underscores, space, then capture any combination of word chars or spaces, then another space.